# Sparx Enterprise architect Create baseline using powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0, enterprise-architect

I want to automatically create a baseline for each project in my enterprise architect project using PowerShell.

> How do you create a baseline from PowerShell?

My code so far gets all the models IE high-level packages for which I want to create a new baseline.

```
$conString = "private connection string"


## implementation do not chage
add-type -path “C:\Program Files (x86)\Sparx Systems\ea\Interop.EA.dll”
$ea = New-Object -ComObject EA.Repository

$ea.OpenFile($conString);

function Process-Packages($packages)
{
  if(!$packages) { throw [System.ArgumentNullException]::new('packages'); }
  if(0 -ge $packages.Count) { return; }

    ## create a baseline for each package
}

foreach($model in $ea.models) 
{ 
  Process-Packages $model.packages;
}

$ea.CloseFile();
$ea.Exit();
```

**Update:**
While using VS I have found the object I am looking for is under **EA.ProjectClass**
which is exposing the relevant functionality to create a package:

```
public virtual bool CreateBaseline(string PackageGUID, string Version, string Notes)
    Member of EA.ProjectClass

Summary:
Creates a baseline on the specified package.

Attributes:
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DispIdAttribute(66)]
```

and there is relative implementation to getbaselines

```
public virtual string GetBaselines(string PackageGUID, string ConnectString)
    Member of EA.ProjectClass

Summary:
Returns an xml string containing the list of guids available for that package.

Attributes:
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DispIdAttribute(65)]
```

Comment: Ok, But you didn't mention the problem you are facing here.

Comment: How about the quote? How do you create a baseline from PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok after going through internet dll's I have found an anwer to my question.

The solution is rather simple, but getting there was painful.

> **Please note**, not all fields such as Author are populated and additional work is required to make it fully usable solution. *This process does bypass configured security for packages.*

### RAW Implementation of the script

```
add-type -path “C:\Program Files (x86)\Sparx Systems\ea\Interop.EA.dll”
$ea = New-Object -ComObject EA.Repository

$ea.OpenFile("private db connection string");

foreach($model in $ea.models) 
{ 
    $eaProject = $ea.GetProjectInterface()
    $eaProject.CreateBaseline($model.PackageGUID,"9.9.9","PowerShell generated")
}

$ea.CloseFile();
$ea.Exit();
```

## Processing info

As mentioned in comments it is time consuming process. For me running this PowerShell on 22k objects it takes about an hour on i3 intel / 4GB RAM

Comment: You can drag the `$ea.GetProjectInterface` outside the loop :-)

Comment: Be careful though, doing this on anything but a trivial demo model will probably run for hours. (if it finishes at all)

Comment: @GeertBellekens Thank you for the comment, I do agree. The whole point is to automate the creation so It can be handed off to a server as a cron job.

Comment: Have you tried the cron job thing? EA needs a logged in user with a license for something like this to work. That is typically not the case on a server. And besides that, what are you going to do with those huge baselines? It seems much better to create smaller baselines at the lower level packages.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Not yet, I have not tried the cron job as yet. For me, it should be ok as I can use my floating license. I gave it a great deal of thought and the outcome is this. A big baseline is better than none, until I get to the point of implementing Git / SVN for this and then the story will change. For me the business who hired me, has decided that buying an exception for git is too expensive.

Comment: I would certainly test the cron job first. That might prove to be a bigger hurdle than you think.